# url data to json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a url which is returning JSON, but due to cross browser request issue I am requesting it with CURL in PHP, now its returning json data as string. I want that string to be converted in to json so I can use it with my javascript function.

Ajax request which is printing JSON string

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'tweet.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            url : url,
        },
        success: function(tweet){
            var tweets = $.parseJSON(tweet);

            console.log(tweets);
        }
    });
```

and in tweet.php

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$ch = curl_init() or die('cURL not available');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST["url"]. $location);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print ($result);
```

Getting Invalid json error

**SOLVED**

Although answers didn't helped, but somehow I figured it out. Posting here if someone need it.

Whenever you request JSON from PHP using Curl it will return the JSON object but as a string, you can check it via javascript typeof() function. If you want to convert that string to real javascript object you need to use some sort of parser. Here what I use 
[JSON PARSER](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/)

```
var myJson = '{ "x": "Hello, World!", "y": [1, 2, 3] }';
var myJsonObj = jsonParse(myJson);
console.log(myJsonObj);
```

Regards

Comment: JSON data as string is JSON. So why can't you simply echo/print the returned value?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921374/how-do-i-convert-a-json-string-to-a-javascript-object-in-jquery

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682260/returning-json-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: check the question again. I have updated it..

Answer (score 1):

Try [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Also as an extra, if you want your php response to be treated as json content use the following pattern in php:

```
// Convert to JSON
$json = json_encode($yourData);

// Set content type
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Prevent caching
header('Expires: 0');

// Send Response
print($json);

exit;
```

Comment: Also, it is not clear why simply getting this with $.getJSON(url) would not work... regardless of what server side is doing, if it returns a valid JSON, then it would still be parsed

Comment: Uncaught Invalid JSON:  This is the error which I am getting, when I am doing "echo" in php

Comment: getJSON will not work as the source is not from the same origin.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Can you provide a sample of the json string you're getting in php?

Comment: @Shiplu the author said he was bringing the data with php curl, so i assume the final url is on same domain...

Comment: acutally i am getting data from Twitter and its very long. its receiveing as string. And I am unable to convert it into the object

Answer (score 1):

In your html file do this assuming `$json` holds the [json](/questions/tagged/json) string returned form remote url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = JSON.parse("<?php echo $json; ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **dataType** from *'text'* to *'json'* in your $.ajax call