# Getting data from json through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to learn how to retrieve data from a json obj that I return from PHP but I can not figure out how to get the values. My data looks something like this:

```
[{"user_name":"herp"},{"email":"herp.derp@gmail.com"},{"yy":"yyyy"},{"mm":"mm"},{"dd":"dd"}]
```

My client-side script looks something like this:

```
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'serverside/get_installningar.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {

        }
    });
```

I would like to type something like data.user_name to retrieve the user_name and so on. But is there a method for doing this? I have looked in the forum but can't find the right thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is an array of objects and so you going to need to know where it is to get `user_name`,

```
data[0].user_name
```

see below for structural details,

```
[
 {"user_name":"herp"},   // <-- data[0]
 {"email":"herp.derp@gmail.com"}, // <-- data[1]
 {"yy":"yyyy"},  // <-- data[2]
 {"mm":"mm"},    // <-- data[3]
 {"dd":"dd"}     // <-- data[4]
]
```

As [AndrewR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197338/getting-data-from-json-through-jquery/13197378#comment17966147_13197378) pointed out,

> This will work, but it would be better to fix the JSON format coming from PHP. `{"user_name":"herp","email":"herp.derp@gmail.com","yy":"yyyy","mm":"mm","dd":"d‌​d"}` and then his original plan will work.

Comment: This will work, but it would be better to fix the JSON format coming from PHP. `{"user_name":"herp","email":"herp.derp@gmail.com","yy":"yyyy","mm":"mm","dd":"dd"}` and then his original plan will work.

Answer (score 0):

use it like:

```
 console.log(data[0].user_name);
```

For a easy acces members of your json, try virtualising it in a nice format so you can understand where you have array and where you have object.

`[]` means array

`{}` means object

I recommand a chrome extension: [JsonView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)

and for example, take a JSON request like [this](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=json&author=screws0ft).

Just open it in a tab and it will be nicely formated.
Also it shows you in the bottom left corner how to access what you are hovering over.

Comment: No; jQuery does that for you.

Comment: dataType : 'json' in the ajax call was enough. But console.log(data[0].user_name); was what I was looking for! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

as of jquery 1.4.1 you can do this natively

`jQuery.parseJSON`

Do that on the data.responseJSON to convert to JS object.

See [How do I convert a JSON string to a JavaScript object in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921374/how-do-i-convert-a-json-string-to-a-javascript-object-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Use [data.parseJSON();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). It returns an object exactly the way you want it.

Comment: No. jQuery already does it for you, since the `dataType` is `json` which will parse the JSON before returning it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually returning an array not a json object

Your data needs to look like this:

```
{{"user_name":"herp"},{"email":"herp.derp@gmail.com"},{"yy":"yyyy"},{"mm":"mm"},{"dd":"dd"}}
```

Try installing Firebug to debug the return value of your page if its a properly formatted JSON.